# Getting CamelHttpResponseCode=400 and HttpOperationFailedException

Tags: java, http, apache-camel

I am getting CamelHttpResponseCode=400 in headers & body is empty.
Can anybody help me in finding the reason behind it.

I am sending json request to server.
Here is my Http Component code.

```
<camel:to uri="{{ServerUrl}}?httpClient.soTimeout=70000&amp;bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=true;transferException=true"/> 
<log message="body  Got ${body}"/>
<log message="header Got ${headers}"/>
```

One thing i notice is when length of request is less than 2000 it works.
It always fails when length of request is more than 2000 & also this request is not hitting the ServerUrl.

En

Comment: It is the server complaining about the request you are sending. So the server logs should tell you what the server is not happy about.

Comment: Server logs tell that there is HttpOperationFailedException & 400 responseCode

Comment: The HttpOperationFailedException is thrown by Camel on the client side. You need to check the server side as to why the server is responding with a status code 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some analysis, I found that size of header is exceeded. Header contains all the form elements which is there in HttpServletRequest of Exchange object.

To remove extra headers i have changed the below code while setting the body of request in camel.

Just replacing getIn() to getOut() solved my problem

```
    exchange.getIn().setBody(JsonUtils.convertToJson(Object));  // Not Working
    exchange.getOut().setBody(JsonUtils.convertToJson(Object)); // It Works
```